# How to select element in if statement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to append an input to products that have a color attribute ( not all products have a color attribute ) so I do something like this:

```
  if ($("#color-selection").length == 0){
      if ($("li.color-select").hasClass("active")) {
        var colorId = $("li.color-select > a").data('color');
        $("div.card-body").hasClass("tt-options-swatch") > $("button.btn-add-to-cart").append('<input type="hidden" id="color-selection" name="color" value="'+colorId+'">');
      }
  }
```

Every thing is ok but it appends to all buttons ( even the ones with or no color)
I just want to append to this conditionally

`$("div.card-body").hasClass("tt-options-swatch")`

Comment: So you want that `tt-options-swatch` expression to be an AND conditional?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, can you add the snippet? You can do so by editing your post and press `ctrl+M` to add the snippet

Comment: I want to append input to   button.btn-add-to-cart    that it has $("div.card-body").hasClass("tt-options-swatch")

Comment: Well you are selecting all elements. Not sure how you think the `$("div.card-body").hasClass("tt-options-swatch") >` changes anything. That line is saying `Boolean > jQuery Object`

Comment: Maybe something like `$("div.card-body.tt-options-swatch").find("button.btn-add-to-cart").append()`? I haven't used jQuery in years but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can solve, i think:

```
$("div.card-body").filter(
     (index, elem) => $(elem).hasClass("tt-options-swatch")
).append('something');
```

or

```
$("div.card-body[class*=tt-options-swatch]").append('something');
```